# Drupal Error After Logging In

Tags: drupal, localhost

I'm kinda new to using drupal and i'm just wondering why I kind of get this error on my new site.

See i have this website under WampServer running drupal6-16. Everytime I log in with my pre-created admin account 'admin01' pass: 'admin01' i get redirected to the WampServer localhost which appears to be unusual since the header does not have the WampServer logo.

I already tried creating a new drupal website with the same database and the same thing happens. Also, I tried creating another website with a new database but I copied the other website's theme and other contents and the same thing happens.

Help me please. I am losing my grip on this. :(

Note: I have the same website running on one PC and i am just trying to run it on another PC by copying all its contents. The original copy is working perfectly but I can't seem to get the hook on my new copies to work on other PCs.

Comment: What is the error? You didn't list it in here.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache, either through the UI, or manually in the database?

Comment: actually it doesn't post any error message. after i click my log in button, it just automatically redirect me to the localhost page (http://localhost/) but the unusual part is that it doesn't have the WampServer logo on its upper-left hand corner. whatever log in credentials I use, it always do the same thing over and over again.

I already tried clearing my cache through the UI but I haven't tried clearing manually through the database. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So I finally figured out what was wrong with my site. Apparently, I don't have my Clean URLs activated on the PC i was running this to. So I had to activate it and tadah, it worked.

Thanks guys. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you have this kind of behavior, you can use the standard way for adminsitrating drupal :

http://localhost/index.php?q=admin